# Why does the file-command states, that executable contains "debug_info"

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I figured out that *file >=5.30* or *gcc >=6.3* have changed it behaviour. When I compile a basic program like a hello-world, the output of *file* indicates that the elf-executable includes some sort of "debug_info".

Source:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv []) {
        cout << "Hello world.\n";
        return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
$ g++ -o hello hello.cpp # notice, no option "-g"
```

Inspect:

```
$ file hello # please scroll to the right hand-side, it is at the very end
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=d03b68ed8618fcb97094b18157054f7cc2030f3c, not stripped, with debug_info
```

I'm not familiar with *readelf*. A *readelf -S hello | grep -i debug* indicates that there is no debug information, when compiled without "-g". If compiled with the option "-g", I see this, which looks fine for me:

```
  [27] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000107c
  [28] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000010ac
  [29] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000038ce
  [30] .debug_line       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00003e54
  [31] .debug_str        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00004186
```

I assume nobody used a hidden configure-flag during build of my *gcc* release, to always include some kind of debug information. So probably the behaviour of the util *file* has changed. What does *file* mean with "debug info"?

Info:
I'm running GNU/Linux (Archlinux) on X86_64, packages are all up-to-date.

Comment: Friendly note: "packages are all up-to-date." does not mean the compiler is or provides any hints at what the compiler version is. The distribution could have stopped updating GCC at 3.3.4 for all we know. That would be extreme, but more than a few major distros seem to have stopped at 4.8 and 4.9. Best to run `g++ -v` and add the version to future questions where required.

Comment: You right, but I added the version-info already at the top of the question. The note at the end, should just give contextual information.

Answer (score 6):

It is a [bug](https://github.com/file/file/commit/0e78a704897cba82924665d3a9de4e520b2ce065#diff-bc5c24ef9f39a5f4963ca28ecbc645b3) and it' is [fixed](https://github.com/file/file/commit/ee13402cb538509f4594a1ebaabc28b7d511c247). The default was 1 (which means 'true') and the fixed changed it to 0 (which means 'false').